# apalike with author (1999) instead of author [1999] in output?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

I'm using the `bibliographystyle{apalike}`, however, I want it to output author(year) instead of author[year] as it does so at the moment, and the paper i'm submitting requires ().

How do I change this behavior?

Comment: If you use `biblatex` with the `apa`style option, this is the default.

Comment: How do I integrate that? I'm using TeXMaker on Linux with bibtex compiling into.

Comment: The texlive-full package, rather. I don't have biblatex.

Comment: Are you using `natbib` or any other package? Can you please show us the relevant settings for your bibliography? The information provided so far is not enough to provide effective help.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific. I'm using `hyperref` as the only package in the document itself. Which packages are included in the ubuntu repo with `texlive-full`, I am not certain.

Comment: Consider this simple document `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xyyzzz.bib}
@article{oskal,
  author = {{\"O}zkal, Erhan},
  title = {The title},
  journal = {The Journal},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {3027-3036}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\cite{oskal}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{xyyzzz}

\end{document}` Save it as is and process it in the usual way to produce the bibliography. Is that what you want?

Comment: It is. Thank you. The hyperref package should work with this also, right? I'll implement this. Thanks again.

Comment: I added the `natbib` and `filecontents` alongside with the bibliographystyle set to `apalike`. All my references changed as I wanted them to. Cheers mate.

Comment: You're welcome. `filecontents` is not really needed. I used it in my example to include the `.bib` file inside the `.tex`. You can have your external `.bib` database and won't need `filecontents`. And yes, it works with `hyperref`; see answer below.

Comment: Cheers. Got it working with hyperref too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `natbib`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xyyzzz.bib}
@article{oskal,
  author = {{\"O}zkal, Erhan},
  title = {The title},
  journal = {The Journal},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {3027-3036}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\cite{oskal}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{xyyzzz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi again. Now natbib is giving me an error: `mybib.bib Repeated entry---line 275 of file mybib.bib :` what's happening here? there is no repeated entry, and every author is fetched directly from google scholar.

Comment: @cbll Since this is not directly related to the issue discussed here, I think the best thing to do is to open a fresh new question. Please provide in this new question a simple test document like the one in my answer, but allowing us to reproduce the problem mentioned.

Comment: Okay I attempted to put it as good as I could in a new post.

Comment: @cbll I little suggestion: add to your new question A little test document (the code) like the one I used in my answer allowing us to reproduce the error.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: @cbll Take a copy of your actual document and start trimming it down, until you get a *complete* document as minimal as possible but still exhibiting the problem.

Comment: Well now we're kinda back to the question i posted here, because the exact same format as I followed(as above) now provides me with `! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.` again.. Why would it do that?

Comment: Bibtex can compile now, but quickbuild provides the above error? I use `\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
`

?

Comment: @cbll PLease add that information to the new question, so more users can have the information.